# Pixelated output even with cm-super and lmodern forces bold W, why?

Tags: output, computer-modern, lmodern, bitmap, pixelated

I have a big problem with Adobe Acrobat Reader. My W's are bold or my ,,t'' and ,,y'' are pixelated regarding which usepackage I am using. This behaviour varies depending on the zoom-level of the pdf-document opened with Adobe Acrobat Reader. The pdf-document in my TexMaker next to the source code is always fine! The pdf-document opened with my Iphone is also fine! My friend with nearly the same set up (see below) has the same problem. It must be Adobe Acrobat Reader!

My setup what I use (everything should be up to date):

-TexMaker

-TexLive (everything should be installed, inclusive cm-super!!)

-Adobe Acrobat Reader DC

Consider my test-file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

Why is this output so strange?[![enter image description here][1]][1]

We will Wuse Wlots of W's in this Wdocument! \\
Änd here äre söme ümläüts. \\
Dony't forgeyt the y's righty herey! \\\\

This one is with textbf: \textbf{W} \\
This one is without bf: W \\
Both together (first bold, then normal): \textbf{W} W \\

\end{document}
```

Now there are three cases regarding using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Case 1: Using neither of them ---> Output is nice (no bold W, no pixelated letters)

Case 2: Using lmodern (with or without T1fontenc) ---> my W are bold.

Case 3: Using only T1fontenc ---> pixelated t and y.

Now let us take a look at the different (important) cases:

Case 2 (using both of the packages):

logfile: https://pastebin.com/y3tXys0L

[image]

Case 3:

logfile: https://pastebin.com/6rnng5C6

[image]

I already tried to change the rendering in Adobe Acrobat: Smooth text for Laptop and un-check ''Enhance thin lines'' etc. It had no effect at all.

My thoughts: Maybe Adobe Acrobat does not ''use the document font'', rather it uses its own fonts?

Edit: If I open the ''pdf-document'' with google chrome, everything is fine!
It must be Adobe Acrobat Reader!!

Comment: You are using three different fonts: cmr10.pfb in case one, lmr10.pfb in case two, sfrm1095.pfb in case three. And obviously adobe reader handles and hints them in a slightly different way.

Comment: It's 2020: Switch to LuaTeX ot XeTeX and use fontspec.

Comment: @MartinSchröder XeLaTex and LuaLaTex should be nicer, or? Do I just have to add `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{lmodern}` ?

Comment: There is the same problem if I use XeLaTex or LuaLaTex with Latin Modern Roman.....